# Error "the Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed did not match the Content-MD5 we calculated for your feed"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, http-headers, content-type

I am trying to set a maximum price for a product using Amazon API in a Django (Python) environment.
I already solved the problem with calculating the md5 function which value is exactly the same as Amazon MWS Scratchpad calculates.

After solving this issue, I get now a "the Content-MD5 HTTP header you passed for your feed did not match the Content-MD5 we calculated for your feed" error message.

My code is as follows:

```
feedTxt = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Header><DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion><MerchantIdentifier>MERCH_ID</MerchantIdentifier></Header><MessageType>Price</MessageType><Message><MessageID>1</MessageID><Price><SKU>J1-1UKW-8Z03</SKU><MaximumSellerAllowedPrice currency="EUR">999</MaximumSellerAllowedPrice></Price></Message></AmazonEnvelope>'

feed = open('myXml.xml', mode='w+', buffering=-1, encoding='utf-8')
feed.write(feedTxt)
feed.close()

encodedFeed = feedTxt.strip().encode('utf-8')

md5 = hashlib.md5(encodedFeed).digest()
encodedMd5 = base64.b64encode(md5)
parsedMd5 = urllib.parse.quote(encodedMd5, safe='')

request_string = construct_strings(seller, '', 'SubmitFeed', '2009-01-01', args_dict) # this function defines the string to be signed and is working 100%, since I use it for all the other requests I do

feed = open('myXml.xml', mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding='utf-8')
myFile = {'file': feed}
response = requests.post(request_string, headers = {'Content-MD5': encodedMd5, 'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}, files = myFile)            
feed.close()
```

It's my first question asked here in stackOverflow.
I appreciate any hints you can give me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to tell you I have solved my issue. I have found that the feed isn't to be posted as a file but in the body ('data' field). Therefore (among plenty of other corrections), the final code is:

```
feed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Header>'
feed += '<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion><MerchantIdentifier>A3RVNLI4ZWO9K4</MerchantIdentifier></Header><MessageType>Price</MessageType><Message><MessageID>1</MessageID>'
feed += '<Price><SKU>sa400240g</SKU><MaximumSellerAllowedPrice currency="EUR">975</MaximumSellerAllowedPrice></Price></Message></AmazonEnvelope>'

encodedFeed = feed.encode('utf-8')
md5 = hashlib.md5(encodedFeed)
encodedMd5 = base64.b64encode(md5.digest())
parsedMd5 = urllib.parse.quote(encodedMd5, safe='')                       

request_string = construct_strings(seller, '', 'SubmitFeed', '2009-01-01', args_dict)
myHeader = {'Content-MD5': encodedMd5.decode('utf-8'), 'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
response = requests.post(request_string, headers = myHeader, data = feed)
```

Thanks, anyway!
Hope this solution helps somebody with the same problem!